# Does strncmp have side effects?

Tags: c++

I have a static checker which complains about usage of strncmp in an if-condition, saying

```
Logical operation performed on expression with possible side effects.
```

Does strncmp have potential side effects or can I ignore this as false positive?

```
if (strncmp(something1, pCurEntry->something2, sizeof(pCurEntry->something2)) == 0)
```

Comment: @Fëamarto added the condition and that is the full Text of the check message.

Comment: There are both no side effects and no logical operators used here, so it seems like your checker is broken. Googling the error message gives only this question as a result - is this an in-house tool?

Comment: Not directly related, but are you sure that `sizeof(pCurEntry->something2)` will return something meaningful here?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want strncmp(something1, pCurEntry->something2, strlen(pCurEntry->something2))? sizeof on a string pointer will always return the pointer size NOT the string length

Comment: @JeffR.There would be no reason to write that instead of simply `strcmp(something1, pCurEntry->something2)`.

Comment: Do you get the same sort of errors with other str functions, such as strlen()? And which static analyser are you using?

Comment: Good catch. I am not sure of anything, I did not write this code. I am just tasked to look at and resolve the findings of the analyzer. Not how I would prefer the process to be, but oh well. I am using QA-C 8.1.1.

Comment: something2 is a char array, not a pointer, so I guess that's fine?(?)

Comment: You might want to read the documentation for your "static checker" to work out what (its developers) consider to be a "side effect" or a "logical operation".    I have certainly encountered people who have funny notions on what such things are - and there is no guarantee that developers of static checkers don't have funny notions.

Comment: Do run-time errors count as side effects? Buffer overrun is a possible case of improper use here.

Comment: strncmp does not have side effects due to it operates only on const pointer and value parameters. Hence either your analyser is buggy or you have side effects somewhere in the remainder of your code. Please include full definition of _pCurEntry_ and _something2_ or at least the full class declaration. It matters due to the type of something2 (_char*_ differs from _char[]_) and the declaration of the class may provide side effects in _operator->_ if your variables are not constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::strncmp` is *not* allowed to have a side effect (the c-style strings are passed `const` for example). With the example you present, your static analyser is issuing a message in error.

But a good static analyser will "complain" about something like

```
(expression) ? n = strncmp(...) : 1
```

as it has a side effect of setting `n` on only a subset of the possible branches. (MISRA disallows that.)